# Pass parameters to AIX server from powershell

Tags: scripting, automation, powershell-2.0, aix

How can I pass parameters to a AIX server using Powershell
Steps to perform:
1.Login to the machine with credentials,
2.Supply values to the AIX prompts(almost 20 prompts).

The goal is to automate the AIX steps using powershell.

Comment: I don't know PowerShell, but most likely it can start `putty` (the ssh client for Windows)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Await' PowerShell module [1] might be worth checking into. As the module's description states, it is an implementation of 'expect' on Windows. expect lets you describe what prompts may show up and how to respond to them.

This post might be useful also:
[Windows expect command equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808546/windows-expect-command-equivalent)

[1] https://msconfiggallery.cloudapp.net/packages/Await/